# How to disable a form when a second form is active

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Windows Forms: FormMain and FormRecordTranslation. I have a menu item on FormMain. When I click the item, I should see FormRecordTranslation form and FormMain must be deactivated i.e. unclickable as long as I am working on second form. when I close the second form, the first form must be available. To this purpose I used the following code inside FormMain class.

```
    public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void recordTranslationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormRecordTranslation frmRecordTranslation = new FormRecordTranslation();
        frmRecordTranslation.Activate();
        frmRecordTranslation.Show();
        frmRecordTranslation.TopMost = true;
    }
}
```

Although this holds the second form on top. it still allows the first form to be clicked and worked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  frmRecordTranslation.ShowDialog() instead of frmRecordTranslation.Show(). This will show your second forma as a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [ShowDialog(Form) (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this purpose.

Also, the `Show()` method has an [overload (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes another form as the parent.

Then, there should be no need for

```
frmRecordTranslation.Activate();
frmRecordTranslation.TopMost = true;
```

any more. But the parent form will still be enabled in this case (just eliminates the need of `TopMost`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `Form.Show()`, like so:

```
frmRecordTranslation.Show();
```

Call the `ShowDialog()` method. `ShowDialog` specifies that the form to be shown is a modal dialog - ie. the form is not able to be interacted with while the dialog is shown, much like message boxes (when displayed using `MessageBox.Show`).